# gradle Execution order

Tags: groovy, gradle, build-script

i'm new to gradle. If i'm not using the either doFirst() or doLast(). In which order the lines in a plugin(say) are executed.  i can observe that they are not executed sequentially?
Can somebody explain the execution  flow of a gradle file?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Gradle build lifecycle is [documented here](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html).

It can be summarized by "ICE": Initialization, Configuration, Execution.

Your question is focused on Execution. For a single-project build, it is described in section "48.5. Configuration and execution of a single project build" at the above link.

For plugins, the task dependency graph will depend on the plugin specifics. For example, see the [Java plugin](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#N11B1C) for a list of its tasks and dependencies.

Comment: Thanks. But i cant clearly get what all executed in configuration phase and what is done in execution phase... can u briefly tell me?

Comment: How is the execution flow of gradle tasks determined in a build.gradle file when no default task is defined and the project is executed by calling the `gradle` command?